# Could anyone suggest the best way to fill large gaps in the drywall under the sink?

Tags: gap

All through our building the area under [image]our sinks looks like this: left side is a 1 inch gap, right side is 2 inches!  I could put in steel wool or spray, but how would I caulk over it?  Any other ideas?  The roaches are unrelenting.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It looks like there are two parallel wall surfaces, one about 3" behind the other, and the front one has holes for placement of the pipes. Is that right? Are both wall surfaces drywall? How are they separated? Where are you located?

Comment: I would guess what we are seeing here is the back of the cabinet has been cut out exposing the plumbing supply lines and the drywall behind it.  That means that its open to the space behind the cabinets.  You're going to have to get creative to close that off.

Comment: Do you rent or own?

Comment: This is from a pre-war apartment building in New York City, finished in 1929.  What you are seeing is a lathe and plaster wall which was covered in drywall.  Then the cabinet was cut out.  So the wall behind the cabinet cut out is the drywall, then there is additional space from the drywall to the lathe just behind the pipes that go into the wall on the far left, which is hard to photograph.  I am rent stabilized, which is something in between owning and renting.  Which is to say, paying a relatively low rent in perpetuity.  A lot of stabilized tenants do major work on their apartments.